# Getting Exception when Trying to run Spring Boot Web test cases. Excpetions : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: AsyncRequestTimeoutException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

In Setup method when I am attaching Rest Controller Advice to mock mvc then below exception is thrown
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/AsyncRequestTimeoutException

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AccountDetailsControllerTest { 

    @Mock
    private AccountDetailService accountDetailService;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new 
                       AccountDetailsController(accountDetailService))
                       .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionControllerAdvice())
                       .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: Getting exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null

 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
 at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(ResourcePatternUtils.java:62)

Comment: post your dependencies, something is missing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, It was issue with Spring dependency. I was using version of 4.3.1 of spring-web and spring boot 1.5.7 expects 4.3.11.